# htaccess RewriteRule only PART of query string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need a request like:

```
www.mydomain.com/books/catalog.html?param1=abc&param2=123param3=etc
```

to internally rewrite so content gets served from:

```
www.mydomain.com/index.php?page=books/catalog.html&param1=abc&param2=123&param3=etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Champion - it works a treat, Thanks! (Just noticed I need more reputation before I can vote you up, but answer accepted)

Comment: Glad it worked out. Acceptance is good enough though now you have good enough reputation to vote up :)